# Amazon SES Not Sending Encrypted Emails

Tags: php, gmail, swiftmailer, amazon-ses

I can't seem to find anything in the Amazon SES documentation about this, but I'm testing out our email sending with Swift Mailer for PHP and Gmail is giving me a little unlocked, red lock next to my emails with the message

> amazonses.com did not encrypt this message

Is this something with Swift Mailer that I have to do (like set an option, etc.) or is this something I would have to set up somewhere in the Amazon SES configuration?

Comment: Do you see this with every message?  Have you configured SPF and DKIM for the domain in SES?  Not that this would really explain it, but it's the only thing that comes to mind.  I don't see this sending SES to Gmail and there should be nothing you can do wrong on the originating side that should trigger this.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That's odd, I came into the office today to continue working on this (we were out of work a lot of last week due to Hurricane Matthew) and it seems to just be working now